# How can I combine if-else statement in one return in reactive programming?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I've got a piece of following code:

```
.flatMap(sth -> {
  obj = sth.getSomeLast();
  if (obj.someField == null) {
    return dao.loadInfo(obj.id).map(info -> Entry(1, 2, info));
  } else {
    return Single.just(Entry(1, 2, null));
  }
})
.doOnNext(entry -> writer(entry));
```

How can I avoid using 2 returns (inside of if/else)? I was thinking about `.filter` and then `defaultIfEmpty()`

Comment: Use ternary (`?:`) perhaps: `return (obj.someField == null) ? dao.loadInfo(obj.id).map(info -> Entry(1, 2, info)) : Single.just(Entry(1, 2, null));`

Comment: Well, there's some piece of code before that loadInfo so I'll have to use a ternary operator like that then: return condition ? getSingleMethod() : Single.just()

Isn't there a better way with using defaultIfEmpty etc?

Comment: You could just try your ideas upfront and see what works for you.

Answer (score 3):

you can use filter and defaultIfEmpty

```
Observable.just("one", "two")
             .filter(s -> !s.equals("a"))
             .map(s -> s + "!")
             .defaultIfEmpty(load());
```

But I don't recommend you to call any method in defaultIfMethod() because 
method load() will be called not depending on result of filter()

That's why you can use

`.switchIfEmpty(Observable.fromCallable(() -> load()))`

swithIfEmpty will work like lazy style, but 
defaultIfEmpty has in parameters some objects and so 
It'll work like eager style